# knockout.js nested looping index

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout binding with `foreach` and inner `foreach` loops. What I need is to apply the alternative row css rule for each even row no matter if it is a child or parent one. If I'm using $index as below, the last child row and first parent might have a same style applied.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr data-bind="css: { alt: $index()%2 }">
        <td colspan="2">
            <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("View", "MyController")?itemId=' + Id() }"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <!-- ko foreach: subItems -->
        <tr data-bind="css: { alt: ($index()+$parentContext.$index()+1)%2 }, visible: $parent.childrenVisible()">
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("View", "MyController")?itemId=' + Id() }"><span data-bind="text: name"></span></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- /ko -->                
</tbody>
```

**Question:** is there a possibility to use a counter in knockout and increment it at each iteration in both parent and child loops? Otherwise what would be a usual technique in this kind of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's far better to deal with styling issues within the stylesheets themselves where possible rather than resorting to code.  This is one instance where you can do so, at least in CSS3.  By using [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), you can apply alternate row styling:

```css
tr {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
```

Comment: Great proposal, but unfortunately need to support IE8 as well. Could use Selectivizr I guess. Curious if there are any other ways.

Comment: @AlexM Just saw your edited comment (wish SO would highlight them being edited!) Yes, Selectivizr is probably appropriate.  I'd rather go that route than having to write extra code to deal with such browsers.  When you no longer need to support them, just remove the script - at least your code is still clean then, rather than leaving a legacy of code that doesn't need to be there.